# Adding a real time chat feature based on Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, chat

I'm building a solution that is based on an Azure Mobile App (server side). I have 3 client applications (a ASP MVC web application, an Android App and an iOS app).
The solution uses a custom authentication provider (token based authentication). I need to add a real time chat feature to it (two persons conversations).

For the mobile apps I think I'm going to work with Azure notification hub (send notification whenever a user sends a message to another) however I'm struggling to find a way to deal with the web frontend app.

Can you suggest some frameworks or tools that I can start with?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *the* one you need: http://signalr.net/

You can use it for your mobile apps as well, there are xamarin components already built for it, for example.  Some sample apps can be found https://github.com/SignalR/Samples

Comment: Is it possible to send notification to the web frontend app from the mobile service app with SignalR?

Comment: @HediNaily - yes it is possible to send notification to web frontend app using SignalR. Though you might end up using Azure Service bus topics for SignalR, but you'll be able to achieve it.

Comment: @HediNaily - any more info you need for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write the chat API on your own and have budget for third party service then you can have look at Moxtra, tokbox.com, twilio etc there are ample of them.